# Docker: Unable to connect to container from host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to use `docker-compose` in order to run an app which consists of 2 container: akka app and postgresql.
Here is yaml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    image: akka-app:latest
    ports:
        - "9000:5000"
  db:
    image: postgres-db:latest
```

After the `docker-compose up` command I see that containers are up and running using `docker ps` command:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
65326e5a9677        akka-app:latest                      "java -cp /..."   40 minutes ago      Up 23 seconds       0.0.0.0:9000->5000/tcp   samplecompose_api_1
1f86273c4f9a        postgres-db:latest                   "docker-ent..."   19 hours ago        Up 23 seconds       5432/tcp                 samplecompose_db_1
```

But when I try to access the **akka-app** from the host via the GET request to `0.0.0.0:9000/status` or `localhost:9000/status` I get back "refused to connect" error in the postman.

Extra information:

- Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
- docker-compose version
- 1.14.0, build c7bdf9e MacOS Sierra 10.12.5

Network settings of the akka-app container:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "5b5b322ffb0fb881317f8cb4e69b8fd887566b8c5b73940174aabace35d816f8",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {
        "5000/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "9000"
            }
        ]
    },
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/5b5b322ffb0f",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "EndpointID": "",
    "Gateway": "",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "",
    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "MacAddress": "",
    "Networks": {
        "pinpointcompose_default": {
            "IPAMConfig": null,
            "Links": null,
            "Aliases": [
                "api",
                "65326e5a9677"
            ],
            "NetworkID": "925c8379c6d5b334177d7d198d1d38e29983903474183bee5734df9d30ab9810",
            "EndpointID": "c7c37f545b00c6a19863315858e93a79f10b54b5675dc2cb8704d2f2f9b2bb1c",
            "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02"
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

docker-compose output:

```
docker-compose up
Starting samplecompose_api_1 ... 
Starting samplecompose_api_1
Starting samplecompose_db_1 ... 
Starting samplecompose_api_1 ... done
Attaching to samplecompose_db_1, samplecompose_api_1
db_1   | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-07-06 08:54:56 UTC
db_1   | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
api_1  | 09:04:26.030 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
api_1  | 09:04:27.472 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO sample-service - Bound to /0.0.0.0:5000
```

Comment: Can you paste docker-compose logs too?

Comment: @dgulabs yes. Just 3 minutes. I'll add the logs to the main question as update :)

Comment: Is wget localhost:9000 failing too? Could you try running the container outside docker-compose via docker run, and binding to a specific address, via "-p IP:host_port:container_port"?

Comment: You could try also netstat from inside the container: docker exec -ti <container_id> netstat -pant

Comment: @dgulabs here is what I get by running the `netstat`: `docker exec -ti 65326e5a9677 netstat -pant
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"netstat\": executable file not found in $PATH"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in an old VirtualBox installed who knows when on my laptop. So while it was installed I could not access running docker containers via `localhost`...
You can [read more](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install) about this on official docker site

After I uninstalled the VirtualBox from the laptop, then restarted the Docker app and relaunched the terminal sessions it was unreal to use `localhost` for access to the containers.

Instead of the localhost I used the IP which I got from the `docker-machine ip default`. But this is not the good way.

So ensure once again that you meet all of the requirements.